# Best way of achieving this background vignetting effect?

Tags: css, background, shadow, vignette

I want to have a vignetting effect on the background of a page I´m building. This is the page:
[www.karolinadahl.se](http://www.karolinadahl.se)

I managed to get the effect I´m looking for in Firefox, and it seems to work ok. In Safari I get some kind of vignetting, though not quite what I´m looking for and the inset shadow slows the page down tremendously for some reason. Im using Safari 5.

I don't think it works in Explorer at all and I don't know about Chrome and Opera.

Is there a smarter way of achieving this effect on the background?

Comment: That is strange, I see it in Firefox 5 and 6. Might be my host, I´ve had problems all day with my changes not showing up, css only partly read etc. Try again later plz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying the effect correctly, however, these effects are

- Not fully supported, which explains your problem with IE
- Known to render differently from browser to browser

Still, time is on your side. Support will only improve. For a web-site still in development, I'd say stick with the CSS3 techniques rather than older, hackier solutions.

You could also try a `gradient` [in the background](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/). Might be more consistent.

Comment: Thanks. Could it be done more concistently with, say, a radial gradient background on top of the regular background? Where the radial gradient would go from say 80% black to 0% i the center. Would such a thing be possible?

Comment: As far as I know, it is. See [here](http://www.westciv.com/tools/radialgradients/index.html) for an example of how to generate the markup.